# styling input type:file inconsistency - FilePath between IE and Firefox (jquery)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to style input type:file.

Problem I've encountered is that in Firefox I don't see file path, while in IE it gives me full file path.

Any way to make these two browsers behave same way?

http://jsfiddle.net/sandrodz/yEG4w/

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is a security feature of the browsers whereby the only information you get is the filename, and the file itself.

Strictly speaking, IE should not give you the full file path of the client machine as it can be used maliciously.

To get just the filename from IE, try this:

```
var filePath = $("#fileInput").val().split("\\");
var fileName = filePath[filePath.length -1];
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yEG4w/1/)

Comment: Should not... but it does... so how do I hide it?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you wanted to show the full path. I've updated my answer for you.

Comment: no problem :=) I didn't explain clearly, I just wanted consistent output, with or without path doesn't matter just same in all browsers.